# Retrieving Wikipedia Data

Tags: php, json

Hi could someone point out and explain where I am going wrong in trying to retrieve data from Wikipedia based on a user's search? Please see the code below. Thanks.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h2>Search</h2>
<form method="post">
  Search: <input type="text" name="q" />
</form>

<?php
// if form submitted
if (isset($_POST['q'])) {


$search = $_POST['q'];
$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
action=query&list=search&srwhat=text&format=json&srsearch={$search}&continue=";
$res = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($res);



?>
<h2>Search results for '<?php echo $_POST['q']; ?>'</h2>
<ol>
<?php foreach ($data->query->search as $r): ?>
  <li><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/
  <?php echo $r['title']; ?>">
  <?php echo $r['title']; ?></a> <br/>
  <small><?php echo $r['snippet']; ?></small></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
<?php 
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following updated code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h2>Search</h2>
<form method="post">
  Search: <input type="text" name="q" />
</form>

<?php
// if form submitted
if (isset($_POST['q'])) {
    $search = $_POST['q'];
    $url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srwhat=text&format=json&srsearch=$search&continue=";
    $res = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($res);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";exit;
?>
<h2>Search results for '<?php echo $_POST['q']; ?>'</h2>
<ol>
<?php foreach ($data->query->search as $r): ?>
  <li><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/
  <?php echo $r->title; ?>">
  <?php echo $r->title; ?></a> <br/>
  <small><?php echo $r->snippet; ?></small></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
<?php 
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Bhumi_Shah thanks however this only appears to display the print_r data, the echo $r['title'] does not show.

Comment: pl remove <pre> tag and exit to display bottom code and tick correct to accept answer

Comment: Hi @Bhumi_Shah sorry for the ignorance but this still has not worked. I commented out the following:                            echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";exit;                                               but I'm probably misunderstanding you

Answer (score 0):

Please remove space before "action" in url

$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
action=query&list=search&srwhat=text&format=json&srsearch={$search}&continue=";

Should Be

$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srwhat=text&format=json&srsearch={$search}&continue=";
You can also use urlencode.